# Hover functionality on box inside a fluidRow in RShiny

Tags: shiny, intro.js

I have a very huge shiny app in which i have multiple fluidRow and each fluidRow has multiple box elements and i want to create a hover funcationilty on all my box elements in fluidRow.

```
    library(shiny)
# library(rintrojs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


  fluidRow(

    box(
      # h3(strong("OVERALL")),
      title = #h3(strong("OVERALL")),
        "OVERALL",
      width = 12,
      status = "primary",
      target = 'row',
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      align='center',
      collapsible = FALSE,
      DT::dataTableOutput("tab_PF1")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {#Server file end

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Looking at the Shiny Tutorials i could see that hover functionality is only applicable on imageOutput and plotOutput

[Hover functionality explained by rshiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/hoverOpts.html)

So is there any solution for this that i can apply hover on my box elements?
please help...
The code is just a sample of it.
please adjust and it would be great if you provide a solution in the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with library `shinyBS` as you can use its functionality `BSTooltip` or `addToolTip` which work on both input and output and in UI and server respectively.

`BSToolTip(title,...)` in UI
`addToolTip(session,title,...)` in server
 can be used for tooltip on : *hover, click, doubleClick*.